# How to create a AWS Lambda like feature using Knative vs Kubernetes

Tags: function, kubernetes, serverless, knative, tekton

I have been trying Knative + Tekton + JenkinX but still not able to replicate somthing similar.

Hello Everyone,
This question is more like a discussion on perspective design in serverless. I would like to create a web based platform where our external client would just pass the docker image location and platform take input and should deploy a function in Knative kubernetes cluster and return should be a DNS endpoint of at web platform of Knative service.

Something similar to of AWS Lambda where you publish a code and call main function and return the  endpoint with code output.

I have been trying Knative + Tekton + JenkinX but still not able to replicate somthing similar.